# Why can't i call props in this Method? (react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My Codeblocks are as follows:

```
class Buerger extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this)
  }
  render() {

    return(
      <div style={{textAlign:"right", marginTop:'-103', marginRight:'900px'}}>
        <Anzeige stand = {"Bargeld: " + this.props.stand}/>
        <Arbeit gehalt = {this.props.gehalt} gehaltChange = {this.gehaltChange} arbeitenFunc = {this.props.arbeitenFunc}/>
      </div>
   )
  }

  gehaltChange(inputWert) {
   const test = this.props.gehalt
    alert(test)
  }
```

So I'm passing the prop "gehalt" from the parent class and you can see i pass it again to a child of the child class called "Arbeit" .

The Funktion gehaltChange is working as checked with an alert('click'), but with this code i get a "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

The passing of gehalt to "Arbeit" is working too as i have tested it as a button name and it shows the right value no problem.

I dont get it. Somebody seeing what i'm doing wrong? Is it that i cant pass props that have been passed before and use them at the same time? I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to pass the constructor the `props` and also call `super` with them.

```
class Buerger extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: don't think that has any effect on the question.

Answer (score 0):

because you changed names

```
this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this)
```

vs

```
gehaltChange={this.gehaltChange}
```

so you bind it into a new name and then pass the original unbound function.

`gehaltChange={this.gehaltHandler}` or `this.gehaltChange = this.gehaltChange.bind(this)`

Comment: Shit right thank you the funktion was working but i didnt actually pass the bound funktion as a prop a name change solved it.

=> gehaltChange = {this.gehaltHandler}

Ill accept the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't binding in a correct way.
Replace this line:

```
this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this);
```

For this one:

```
this.gehaltChange = this.gehaltChange.bind(this);
```

And pass props as someone replied above.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this)
  }
```

to this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.gehaltHandler = this.gehaltChange.bind(this);
  }
```

You missed the `props` argument in both `constructor`and `super` methods :)